# Store input select option into database

Tags: php, sql, html

I want to save the input select option in the database with value of the option. But nothing is getting saved. What is wrong? I am saving the value as `varchar (10)` in the database.

**FORM**

```
<form name="stdntdetails" action="study.php" method="post">
    <select name="department">
        <option value="IT">Information Technology</option>
        <option value="IS">Information System</option>
        <option value="CS">Computer Science</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" id="loginbtn" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
require_once("navig.php");
require_once('connect.php');
$dbb = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
  or die('Error communicating to MySQL server.');
if(isset($_POST['loginbtn'])){
  if(isset($_POST['department'])){
    $department=$_POST['department'];
    $querye = "INSERT INTO tbl_name(department) ".
                        "VALUES ('$department')";
    $sql=mysqli_query($dbb,$querye);
    mysqli_close($dbb);                     
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the value in `$_POST['department']`. Try `echo $_POST['department'];`

Comment: edit this question to your edited code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several errors in your code. Try the following:

**FORM**

```
<form name="stdntdetails" action="study.php" method="post">
    <select name="department">
        <option value="IT">Information Technology</option>
        <option value="IS">Information System</option>
        <option value="CS">Computer Science</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" id="loginbtn" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
require_once("navig.php");
require_once('connect.php');
$dbb = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
  or die('Error communicating to MySQL server.');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if(isset($_POST['department'])){
    $department=$_POST['department'];
    $querye = "INSERT INTO tbl_name (department) VALUES ('$department')";
    $sql=mysqli_query($dbb,$querye);
    mysqli_close($dbb);                     
  }
}
?>
```

I tested the code and it works just fine. The query sent to MySQL is:

> INSERT INTO tbl_name (department) VALUES ('IT')

Answer (score 2):

change your query like this

```
$querye = "INSERT INTO tbl_name(department) VALUES ('$department')";
```

and

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

and

```
<input type="submit" id="loginbtn" value="submit" />
```

Comment: @ABHI_SINGH it's actually a lot easier to keep querys in one line. 

Comment: you didn't have value for submit button and you are checking if(isset($_POST['loginbtn'])). so the condition fails. this is your problem

Comment: not only the query try setting value to submit button and check that value as isset($_POST['submit button value']).

Comment: Did same as you said still no value went to db.All connections right and other inputs ex text working perfectly

Comment: just a try, $querye = "INSERT INTO tbl_name(department) VALUES ('".$department."')"; try this query

Answer (score 2):

Change this query

```
$querye = "INSERT INTO tbl_name(department) ".
                        "VALUES ('$department')";
```

to

```
$querye = "INSERT INTO tbl_name(department) 
                        VALUES ('$department')";
```

Also try

```
<input type="submit" id="loginbtn" name="loginbtn" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: @ABHI_SINGH, below `if(isset($_POST['loginbtn'])){`, put `echo "Success"`. Show the result!. Edited the code. Try again

Comment: getting success there but still no value getting stored

Comment: As another try, below `$department=$_POST['department'];` put `echo $department;` What you are getting ? @ABHI_SINGH

Comment: <input type="submit" id="loginbtn" value="submit" id="loginbtn" />when value is submit getting nothing on echoing and when value is login btn getting nothing too.Please help

Comment: why use 2 times id element `id="loginbtn"`. Remove it. Instead of it put `name="loginbtn"`. If you are not getting the value of `$department`, then how can it gets store in the database?

Comment: Did what u said now on echoing getting $department not the value

Answer (score 1):

make your query like -

```
"INSERT INTO tbl_name(department) VALUES ('$department')";
```

and set the name of submit button

```
<input type="submit" id="loginbtn" name="loginbtn" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to echo your $_POST("department"); if display the right value then there's a problem with the query.

try this:

```
$querye = "INSERT INTO tbl_name(department) VALUES ('$department')";
```